# Calculate sum of command line arguments and display the result

Tags: bash

Write a bash script that adds its command line arguments and display the result. Assume command line arguments are all integers apart from the argument itself.

So for example:

```
% addprogram 2 5 7
The total is 14
```

I've tried all I can and can't seem to find anything on the net, please keep the answer really simple.

I've tried stuff like:

```
#!/bin/bash

total += $@
```

But I don't think that operator exists in bash.

My algorithm would be something like this:

1. For argument passed from the command line,
2. Add the first argument to the total,
3. move onto the next argument and add that to the total,
4. repeat as long as there are arguments
5. output total

Comment: Write a StackOverflow question that doesn't look like you pasted your homework in, didn't bother to read anything ("can't seem to find anything" == "Google didn't hand me a script in the first 5 results") and isn't so trivial that to not learn this will severely handicap you for the next assignments. Are you being forced to take this course by an oppressive, totalitarian, technocracy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

posix compatible version:

```
for i do
    sum=$(expr $sum + $i)
done
echo $sum
```

Note that by default `for` iterates over `$@`.

Answer (score 10):

Because nobody's done it yet

```
IFS=+
bc<<<"$*"
```

Using `bc` gets you bignums; shell builtin arithmetic fails when the numbers are huge.

`expr` may or may not do bignums depending on whether it's a recent GNU coreutils version.

The `IFS` and `<<<` are just tricks to make it shorter. A more understandable version would be

```
echo $* | sed 's/ /+/g' | bc
```

Comment: This is cool hackish solution. +1. Remember to revert IFS, or run it all in a `(` subshell `)`.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
for n in $@
do
  let sum=$sum+$n
done
echo The total is $sum
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! I was missing 'let' in the one I had...

Answer (score 2):

I'd do it like this:

```
total=0

for i in $@; do
  (( total+=i ))
done

echo "The total is $total"
```

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly as well! Which one is more correct? the one above or this one?

Answer (score 2):

I like `awk`, so I'd do it like this:

```
echo $@ | tr ' ' '\n' | awk '{sum+=$0}END{print sum}'
```

And a pure-bash version could go like:

```
echo $@ | tr ' ' '\n' | ( sum=0; while read; do sum=$((sum+REPLY)); done; echo $sum )
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the steps you have provided, with `shift` and `expr`:

```
sum=0
while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    sum=`expr $sum + $1`
    shift
done
echo $sum
```

Comment: Thanks to you aswell, this one also works a charm! I had saw the 'expr' but I was unsure how to use it. Which one of these answers is most correct?

Comment: @classA All of them look to be correct, you are in a very comfortable situation when you can select the solution that suits you best :)